# Stuck with perl code

Tags: perl

I have a text file with a list like this:

```
test1:test2
test3:test4
test5:test6
```

and I'd like to import it in a *hash* (with the left word as a key and the right word as the value.

My code is like this:

```
open FILE1, "text_file_with_words.txt" or die;
my %hash;

while (my $line=<FILE1>) { 
   chomp($line);
   (my $word1,my $word2) = split /:/, $line;  
       $hash{$word1} = $word2;   
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%hash;
```

I m getting below output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'test1' => 'test2',
      'test5' => 'test6',
      'test3' => 'test4'
    };
```

Now, I am not getting idea how could I change my code to extend the output finally as shown below:

```
$VAR1={
         'test2' =>'test6'=>'test4'
      };
```

Can someone help me to get this output?

Comment: The desired output does not make sense as a Perl hash.  You're going to have to explain better what you are after.  The output you're actually getting is the expected result.

Comment: Your current output is exactly what you want. It's a hash. You don't want what you think you want. That's not a hash.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I agree, that my first output is the expected output from the above written code. But Now, I want to amend the code to get output like below or I can say that I want to make a "hash of hash". Desired output: $VAR1={
         'test2' =>'test6'=>'test4'
      };

Comment: David and Jim are correct, the desired example output does not make sense. Are you are looking for something more in the format of $hash->{"test2"}->{"test6"}->{"test4"}="SomeValue" or @array=["test2", "test6", "test4"]? What happens to "test1", "test5", "test3"? Sorry, but the relationship between the data you have in the example and what you are trying to store is unclear, but I suspect you may be looking for more of an array solution rather than a hash structure.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
print Dumper( [values %hash] );
```